# Stored procedure to update parent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables for representing sensors and their values:

```
Unit:
  id
  name
  last_data

Data:
  id
  timestamp
  temperature
  unit
```

So basically I have multiple `Data` rows for each `Unit`.

I want to add a SP so every time I insert a `Data` row, it will automatically update `last_data` column in the matching parent (to point to the newly create `id`.

```
pseudo code:

new_id = INSERT INTO Data (temperature, unit) VALUES (25, 1);

UPDATE Unit SET last_data = new_id WHERE id=1
```

Not sure how to write such procedure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can help you to solve you problem:

```
INSERT INTO Data (temperature, unit) VALUES (25, 1);
```

this our trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_last_data 
    AFTER INSERT ON 'Data' for each row
begin
    SET @last_id_in_data = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    UPDATE Unit SET last_data = @last_id_in_data WHERE id=1;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the ID of the last record that you've created within your session.

So you pseudo code would become something like:

```
INSERT INTO Data (temperature, unit) VALUES (25, 1);
SET @new_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
UPDATE Unit SET last_data = @new_id WHERE id=1
```

Or even shorter:

```
INSERT INTO Data (temperature, unit) VALUES (25, 1);
UPDATE Unit SET last_data = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE id=1
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: @GiladNovik: ask a new question then. Your original question asked for something different. If you change the question, all answers become invalid.